# Optimization problem with the Harmonic number

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, linearization

I have an optimization problem:

\begin{align*}
\text{ minimize } \sum_{i=1}^n H(x_i) 
\\
\text{ subject to } Ax \geq b, x\geq 0, x\in \mathbb{Z}^n
\end{align*}

where $H(n)$ is the $n$-th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). How can I model this harmonic number in an ILP solver in an efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $x_i$ has upper bound $u_i$. Introduce binary variable $y_{ij}$ to indicate whether $x_i=j$, and minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{u_i} H(j)y_{ij}$$
subject to additional constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_j y_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
\sum_j j y_{ij} &= x_i &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

Comment: What if there is no predefined upper bound? Or if the upper bound is very large, so this scheme will lead to a very high number of binary variables?

Comment: To get a valid upper bound $u_i$ for each $i$, you can maximize $x_i$ subject to the original constraints.  To avoid a large number of binary variables, you can solve the problem in stages.  Start with a coarser discretization than $\{0,\dots,u_i\}$ and gradually refine it in the neighborhood of the most recent solution.

Comment: "gradually refine it in the neighborhood of the most recent solution" - it sounds like a kind of a local search. Is it guaranteed to find the global optimum?

Comment: You could do the refinement heuristically or exactly.  One exact approach is to use *sifting* (column generation with a precomputed complete pool of columns).  The column generation subproblem reduces to explicitly searching the pool for a negative reduced cost column.

Comment: Also, since $H_n$ increases to infinity as $n \to \infty$, any feasible solution gives a (though very large) upper bound of all $x_i$s.